# How to Check that image already exists/attached while Uploading multiple images at a time in c#, asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am going to upload multiple images using asp.net file upload control. there are many suggestions in mind for this solution..
currently am using DataTable . all images put in DataTable view state and then while checking its rows.. I mark a Check on FileName if already exists then it will not Upload.. But
if any user browse/upload an image having same name but from different Folder/Path it will become an issue. my code is here

```
 private void AttachImage()
        {
                string fileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
                string filePath = "images/" + fileName;
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(ImageUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                ImageUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
                dc = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);

                dc = new DataColumn("Path", typeof(String));
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);

                dt.Rows.Add(fileName, filePath);
                if (ViewState["dt"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                }
                else// (ViewState["dt"] != null)
                {
                    DataTable tmpTable = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                    tmpTable.Rows.Add(fileName, filePath);
                    ViewState["dt"] = tmpTable;
                }


            lstProductsImage.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
            lstProductsImage.DataBind();

        }
```

Secondly: using GUID , to assign images. but it will also not suitable as it will only change the FileName and we are not able to determine whether this file exist on the server or not.
Third Option can be that if the file already exists in the upload folder we ask the user if he/she wants to overwrite the existing file.
Or I should use `System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))` ??

I want Good Suggestions from your side ...
Thanks:
Saquib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude!
I review your code and from my point of view...
1- Dont Use GUID in this senario.
2- Get File Name using Following code (Change it as per your requirement)

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dsPhotosFiles.Tables[0].Rows[i]["filePath"].ToString());
```

3- Get Image Bytes using array (for example byte[] imageBytes;)

```
byte[] imageBytes;
  imageBytes = (byte[])dsPhotosFiles.Tables[0].Rows[i]["fileBytes"];
```

OR  Read file into a data stream  AND && Put a Check on FileName + FilePath using((System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(SavePath + Filename))) )    + ImageBytes

byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];

4- After that Check whether the file is really a JPEG by opening it (can get some help from following code..

```
System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallBack = 
                       new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        Bitmap myBitmap;

       try
        {
            myBitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));

            // If jpg file is a jpeg, create a thumbnail filename that is unique.
            file_append = 0;
            string sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                                                     + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile)))
            {
                file_append++;
                sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName) + 
                               file_append.ToString() + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            }

            // Save thumbnail and output it onto the webpage
            System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail
                    = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(intThumbWidth, 
                                                 intThumbHeight, myCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);
            myThumbnail.Save (Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile));
            imgPicture.ImageUrl = sSavePath + sThumbFile;

            // Displaying success information
            lblOutput.Text = "File uploaded successfully!";

            // Destroy objects
            myThumbnail.Dispose();
            myBitmap.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException errArgument)
        {
            // The file wasn't a valid jpg file
            lblOutput.Text = "The file wasn't a valid jpg file.";
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));
        }
```

Hope This will be Helpful to You...
Regards:
Azeem Raavi

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowing duplicates (and there is a check in place), why would you rename the files?  Just save them under their original name and use the File.Exists check when subsaquent uploads are performed.

Also, you concern about the folder/path wouldn't be an issue because all files are uploaded to the images folder based on your code.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question properly. That guy meant that if user selects an image abc.png from folder A and uploads it. Then he selects another DIFFERENT image from folder B and if that image has the same name abc.png then his check on image name will not allow to upload the image because image with the same name already exists in the table. and that's his problem.

Comment: If thats the case, I think the system needs to be more advanced because there would be no way to differentiate the two files as all he is taking from the upload is the file name.  So even if he used GUIDs, the file path saved would be identical after upload (images/abc.jpg).  Additionally, the use of ViewStates is a very temporary solution for saving the data, as soon as the page is visited without postback, the data is gone.  And after that the File.Exists would no longer work as the GUID file names would all be unique.

Answer (score 0):

let you try in Java script,may be that's help you know

in my aspx flie in java code

```
$("#UPLOAD_BUTTON").uploadify({
                  'buttonClass'   : "ui-icon ui-icon-plus",
                  'swf'            : '/web/uploader/uploadify.swf',                  
                  'uploader'       : '/web/uploader/Uploadify.ashx?ASPSESSID=<% =Session.SessionID %>',
                  'cancelImage'    : '/web/uploader/uploadify-cancel.png',
                  'folder'         : '/uploads',
                  'multi'          : true,
                  'auto'           : true,
                  'checkExisting'  : '/web/uploader/Uploadify.ashx?check=true',
                  'queueID'        : "UploadFilesQueue",
                  'buttonText'     : ' ',          
                  'hideButton'     : true,  
                  'fileTypeExts'   : '*.*',
                  'fileTypeDesc'   : 'Alle Dateien',
                  'onQueueComplete': function(event,data) {                      
                  },
                  postData : {
                    "stepID" : $("#lblStepID").text(),
                    "ASPSESSID" : "<% =Session.SessionID %>",                    
                  }
              });
```

you need to pass the SessionID as a parameter and grab it in the Global.asax File or you will create a new ASP.NET session on every Upload.

In the jquery.uploadify.js File you need to find this function and modify it

```
function onUploadStart(file)
```

here you can react on the Returncode from you Upload-ASHX file.

I use different return codes for different conditions like

```
ReturnCode=1 -> File allready Exists
ReturnCode=2 -> File is to Big
```

....